# Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Rating::setPost() must be an instance of App\Entity\Post or null - Symfony4

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

I am new to Symfony4. I have a problem related to the set value in the table by click button. I want to store the user id and post id in the table by click on the like button, but it gives me an error.

I am passing the post id through the route and it should be stored in the database but it doesn't. please help me to solve my problems. I am giving all my codes here is my Entity:

**App/Entity/Rating.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\RatingRepository")
 */
class Rating
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\user", inversedBy="ratings")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\post", inversedBy="ratings")
     */
    private $post;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?user
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?user $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPost(): ?post
    {
        return $this->post;
    }

    public function setPost(?post $post): self
    {
        $this->post = $post;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**App/Entity/Post.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\File(
     *      maxSize = "30M"
     * )
     */
    private $attachment;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"published"="DESC"})
     */
    private $published;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Rating", mappedBy="post")
     */
    private $ratings;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ratings = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAttachment(): ?string
    {
        return $this->attachment;
    }

    public function setAttachment(?string $attachment): self
    {
        $this->attachment = $attachment;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPublished(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->published;
    }

    public function setPublished(\DateTimeInterface $published): self
    {
        $this->published = $published;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Rating[]
     */
    public function getRatings(): Collection
    {
        return $this->ratings;
    }

    public function addRating(Rating $rating): self
    {
        if (!$this->ratings->contains($rating)) {
            $this->ratings[] = $rating;
            $rating->setPost($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeRating(Rating $rating): self
    {
        if ($this->ratings->contains($rating)) {
            $this->ratings->removeElement($rating);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($rating->getPost() === $this) {
                $rating->setPost(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**App/Entity/User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OrderBy;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, message="There is already an account with this username")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"published"="DESC"})
     */
    private $posts;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Follower", mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $followers;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Rating", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $ratings;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->followers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->ratings = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
        ]);
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return [
            'ROLE_USER'
        ];
    }

    public function getSalt() {
        return null;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials() {
        $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Post[]
     */
    public function getPosts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->posts;
    }

    public function addPost(Post $post): self
    {
        if (!$this->posts->contains($post)) {
            $this->posts[] = $post;
            $post->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePost(Post $post): self
    {
        if ($this->posts->contains($post)) {
            $this->posts->removeElement($post);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($post->getUser() === $this) {
                $post->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Follower[]
     */
    public function getFollowers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->followers;
    }

    public function addFollower(Follower $follower): self
    {
        if (!$this->followers->contains($follower)) {
            $this->followers[] = $follower;
            $follower->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFollower(Follower $follower): self
    {
        if ($this->followers->contains($follower)) {
            $this->followers->removeElement($follower);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($follower->getUser() === $this) {
                $follower->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Rating[]
     */
    public function getRatings(): Collection
    {
        return $this->ratings;
    }

    public function addRating(Rating $rating): self
    {
        if (!$this->ratings->contains($rating)) {
            $this->ratings[] = $rating;
            $rating->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeRating(Rating $rating): self
    {
        if ($this->ratings->contains($rating)) {
            $this->ratings->removeElement($rating);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($rating->getUser() === $this) {
                $rating->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Route to pass the post id**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Post;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Follower;
use App\Entity\Rating;
use App\Form\PostType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class PostController extends AbstractController
{ 
   /**
     * @Route("user/like/{id}")
     */
    public function like(Request $request, $id){
        $like = new Rating();

        $like->setPost($id);
        $like->setUser($this->getUser());
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($like);
        $entityManager->flush();


        return $this->redirectToRoute('twitter');
    }
}
```

**Error Message found in the browser**
Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Rating::setPost() must be an instance of App\Entity\Post or null, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\spractice-backup\src\Controller\PostController.php on line 25

thanks in advance

Comment: You have to pass the `Post` object to `setPost`, so you have to load it from the database beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just set id to Doctrine's relation. You need to get whole `Post` entity from repository. Try something like this:

```
    /**
     * @Route("user/like/{id}")
     */
    public function like(Request $request, $id){
        $post = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Post::class)->find($id);
        if (!$post) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('The post does not exist');
        }

        $like = new Rating();

        $like->setPost($post);
        $like->setUser($this->getUser());
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($like);
        $entityManager->flush();


        return $this->redirectToRoute('twitter');
    }
```